# Updating trigger in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: mysql, sql, database, visual-studio-2010

I have a problem with my SQL trigger in Visual Studio 2010. I have 2 tables and I'd like to make an operation with one table on another.

here's the code:

```
ALTER TRIGGER update_costs
ON employees
AFTER UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    UPDATE employees
    SET salary = 0
    WHERE NewSalary.ID=employees.ID
    PRINT 'Salary is now set on 0'

END
```

I'd like it to work like that:

- I'm setting salary in NewSalary table on 0
- Salary in employees table is changed to 0

The error I'm getting is

> "multi-part identifier "NewSalary.ID" could not be bound"

I assume there is no "inner join" but i don't know how to use it

Comment: You are correct that you need a join, but you also need to use the "hidden" *inserted* table, which will contain the record ID of the new record going into the employees table.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the `ON Employees` to `ON NewSalary`.

It can't find NewSalary.ID because the NewSalary table is not referenced.

When I'm having problems with SQL I usually talk them out to compare the logic

Old:
After every update to Employees, update employees and set salary = 0 where NewSalary.ID = employees.ID.

New:
After every update to NewSalary, update employees and set salary = 0 where NewSalary.ID = employees.ID.

See the difference?

Comment: employees is the table the trigger is on, not the table that needs to be joined. At least that's how I read the question.

Comment: Note how the asker **wants** the trigger to work. The initial action is upon the NewSalary table. As upon a result to that update on the NewSalary table - something else should happen to the Employees table

Comment: You're right. Except that's poor design to have the salary recorded in both places. Something is off.

Comment: I agree in regards to DB design